# SDK Android studio is not downloaded

Tags: android

i have downloaded android studio in windows 10 but the download of the SDK is blocked here , like it is presented in the picture . how can i fix that please [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTTjg.jpg)

i tried to download it using a good quality of network but it failed and even the download process did not start